# What is the source for the statement that red hands were used as a symbol of protest against the Vietnam War?

Tags: vietnam-war, symbols, protests

I have [read](https://designobserver.com/feature/the-red-hand--a-graphic-history/4477) that the red hand, or rather hands painted with red color, have been used as a symbol of protests against the Vietnam War:

> During the Vietnam era, it was a symbol calling for strikes against the war.

Unfortunately, the links provided in the article don't work anymore and the author, William Drenttel, passed away some years ago.

I am looking for sources for this statement, ideally photographs online, but also mentions in articles, books, etc.

Comment: I was very much alive back then. but I never saw it or heard of it.

Comment: Likewise, I was well aware what was going on back then and never heard of it. You're on saver grounds with the ban the bomb symbol. That wasn't strictly speaking against Vietnam, but for nuclear disarmament, but it was widely used as anti war symbol.

Comment: There are oodles of pictures of Vietnam war protests too. If that was A Thing, it shouldn't have been very difficult to find. I believe **the** icon of the Vietnam Protests was the Peace Symbol. Its now so ubiquitous that there's a standard emoji for it, but it was only designed in 1958 (for nuclear disarmament) but a decade later became synonymous in the US with being specifically against the Vietnam War.

Comment: Maybe this I guess? https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/printed-in-1968-by-students-at-the-rhode-island-school-of-news-photo/524559714